# cakePHP find() returns field name instead of just the column values

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.3

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database using the find() method.

But when I use find('all') it returns the column value and column name together, like this: **{ "date_1": "2015-25-12"}**, of course, I want only the values from the column.

If I use find('list'), it comes back empty.

This is how I'm trying to retrieve my data:

```
$date1 = $this->Stocks->find('all', ['fields' => ['Stocks.date_1'], 'conditions' => ['Stocks.families_id' => $id]]);
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks
(
  families_id integer,
  date_1 date NOT NULL,
  date_2 date,
  created timestamp without time zone,
  modified timestamp without time zone,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT stocks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Everything else is working fine, but this one part. 
I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you specified in the model what's your primary key and your display field?

Comment: I used bake, so displayField and primary key are set to `id`.

Comment: But you said that if you find "list" the result is empty. If that's happening, something is wrong.

Comment: Put a sample of the data returned. Also, check this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

Comment: Fixed the problem. I had to set `displayField` to `date_1`. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Although you problem was related to `displayField`.

To select a single column or a set of columns you can do like this

```
$date1 = $this->Stocks->find()
         ->select(['date_1'])
         ->where(['families_id' => $id]);
```